# Как вывести числа от 3 до -3 в одну строку?

Tags: python

### Считалочка 2.0

Дети продолжают запоминать цифры, а мы им помогать.
Нам вновь называют начало и конец последовательности чисел, а мы выводим их и числа между.

### Формат ввода

Два числа, каждое с новой строки.

### Формат вывода

Все числа от начала до конца (включительно), записанные через пробел.

### Пример 1

*Ввод*

1

10

*Вывод*

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

### Пример 2

*Ввод*

3

-3

*Вывод*

3 2 1 0 -1 -2 -3

Задача лёгкая, сама понимаю, но я испробовала кучу вариантов решения, которые Яндекс благополучно отклоняет. Моя единственная проблема: не знаю как вывести второй пример. Прошу помочь, господа товарищи.

Comment: У функции `print` есть аргумент `end`...

Comment: вопрос не в этом

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вашу попытку решить и почему не сработало. Иначе вопрос закроют - правила.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
start = int(input())
end = int(input())

if start <= end:
    step = 1
else:
    step = -1

while start != end + step:
    print(start, end=" ")
    start += step
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Осталось избавиться от пробела в конце строки и перевести строку на новую.

Answer (score 2):

- Вычислите направление в котором собираетесь идти - `step`.
- Поправьте правый конец - `b + step`. Иначе он не будет напечатан.
- перечислите числа с помощью [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) и напечатайте сразу все с помощью `print(*...)`:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())

# step = 1 if a <= b else -1
if a <= b:
    step = 1
else:
    step = -1

print(*range(a, b + step, step))
```

Answer (score -3):

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
for i in range(a,b+1):
    print(i)
if b<a:
    while b<a+1:
        print(a)
        a-=1
```

Код прост поэтому обьяснять его нет смыла

Comment: пробовала такое решение, увы, но не принимает

Comment: я не знаю как работает Яндекс тесты.Может у тебя тебя пишет какой тест провалялся?)

Comment: Печатать в одну строку данный код не будет